# Can we have a feature to shorten answers?

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

Some questions solicit, by their nature, have many answers. For example [Showcase of Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-of-languages) or [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics). Could we have a feature to hide comments, and shorten long answers (to perhaps their first line or so), so you can browse through many answers quickly?

Comment: @Catija That applies to just one post at a time. I'm talking about all the posts at once.

Comment: Your question says nothing of the sort. If you want your question to be understood, make it longer than three sentences.

Answer (score 4):

These are very exceptional "questions" indeed. Developing a feature for a handful of those does not seem warranted.

If having a way to overview the hundreds of answers is important, one can write a "table of contents" and edit it into the question (or, if this is undesirable, put in *another* question), with each line linking to the answer. This would bring some structure to the list: table of contents could have sections for various areas of mathematics or language groups. Thematic grouping makes more sense with hundreds of answers than any automatic sort of the flat list.

There is an example of such ToC: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: There is a "table of contents" in the Showcase of Languages in the form of a Stack Snippet